# How to get namedGroup and the value of input associated? matcher.group()

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following code:

```
String regExp = "^.{10}(?<Animal>.{10})(?<Country>.{10})(?<Fruit>.{10}).{5}(?<Movie>.{10})";
String line = " Start:   Dog       Japan     apple          Godfather "

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);
```

However 'matcher' group (matcher.group(int)) they are all returning -1

How can I get the values "Dog", "Japan", "apple","GodFather"?

Comment: Why not use `line.split()?`  Or maybe just `line.substring(10,10)`?

Comment: For your example the groups are returned successfully both by name and id.

Comment: 'Cause it's just a example. The project is bigger xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These values are returned successfully:

```
String regExp = "^.{10}(?<Animal>.{10})(?<Country>.{10})(?<Fruit>.{10}).{5}(?<Movie>.{10})";
String line = " Start:   Dog       Japan     apple          Godfather ";

List<Map<String, String>> rows = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<>();
    row.put("Animal", matcher.group("Animal"));
    row.put("Country", matcher.group("Country"));
    row.put("Fruit", matcher.group("Fruit"));
    row.put("Movie", matcher.group("Movie"));
    rows.add(row);

    System.out.println(matcher.group("Animal"));
    System.out.println(matcher.group("Country"));
    System.out.println(matcher.group("Fruit"));
    System.out.println(matcher.group("Movie"));

    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
}
```

outputs:

```
Dog       
Japan     
apple     
Godfather 
Dog       
Japan     
apple     
Godfather
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Why when I use while(matcher.matches()) It doesn't even enter the loop?

Comment: while(m.matches()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount() - 2; i += 2) {
     for(int groupCtr =1; groupCtr < m.groupCount()-1; groupCtr++) {
      grupo = m.group(groupCtr);
      documento.campos.put(m.group(groupCtr),grupo.trim());
      System.out.println(m.group(groupCtr)+ " > " + grupo);
     }
    }
   }

Comment: In this case `while(m.matches())` turns into endless loop. Do you mean `m.find()`?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. You helped me a lot! Thank very much, Alex!

Comment: `m.find()` detects a substring, and `m.matches()` is applied to entire string. so, providing that you did not use `^` in the beginning of your pattern, for a long 110-char string you could have a case when `m.matches` is false and `m.find` could detect the groups twice.

Comment: Do you know how can I get the groupnames? I want to associate the groupname with the value. Then I will put all in a HashMap.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  The group names are already defined in your regexp in angle brackets `?<Animal>` etc.

Comment: I want to create a HashMap.put( "the groupname<Animal>","value<dog>"). The input have many lines, the ideia is to make a HashMap for each line and put into a List. Each position in the list will have the HashMap that will fill up a document.

Comment: Resuming up: When I call an animal, a dog comes.

Comment: Making an association with the group name and values :)

Comment: matcher.group(2) is the Japan, but Japan is what in the Groupnames? This is the question

Comment: groupName for Japan is Country

Comment: I want in output: "Country = Japan"

Comment: Please check the update - you'll get list of maps (though it'd be better to implement a POJO and have code like `rows.add(new MyRow(matcher.group("Animal"), matcher.group("Country"), matcher.group("Fruit"), matcher.group("Movie")))`)

Comment: The Regex is not fixed, so I didn't want to write them all in the code. But thanks for tried to help :)